# How can I calculate the maximum center load on a horizontal cellular glass tile; supported along its edges, before it breaks?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, beam, material-science

Insulating cellular glass boards or tiles are designed to sit on a flat load-bearing surface. I want to consider the situation where the base is concave so the tile is only supported on its edges. I would like to be able to calculate the minimum thickness to width (square tile) ratio needed to support a certain center load under these conditions without the tile breaking.

The specs provided for the material are:

- compressive strength > 1600 kPa;
- bending strength > 550 kPa;
- tensile strength perpendicular to faces > 200 kPa